# vue-router redirect not working on route push

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following router configured:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',

  routes: [
    // root
    {
      path: '/',
      component: ComponentPage,
      redirect: routePrefix.public,
      children: [

        // public
        {
          path: routePrefix.public,
          component: ComponentPage,
          redirect: `${routePrefix.public}/login`,
          children: [
            {
              path: `${routePrefix.public}/login`, component: LoginPage,
            }],
        },

        // private
        {
          path: routePrefix.private,
          component: ComponentPage,
          children: [
            {
              path: `${routePrefix.private}/u`, component: PrivatePage,
            }],
        }],
    }],
});
```

now as you can see, there are two main parts; a public, and a private one.
Additionally I have the following navigation guard configured for authorization:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(`registered request to redirect from 
    '${from.fullPath}' to '${to.fullPath}'`);

  if (to.fullPath.startsWith(routePrefix.private) &&
    !Store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']) {
    console.log('-> reroute to public main');
    next(routePrefix.public);
  } else if (to.fullPath.startsWith(routePrefix.public) &&
    Store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']) {
    console.log('-> reroute to private main');
    next(routePrefix.private);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

If you're wondering what the route prefix look like, here you go:

```
const routePrefix = {
  public: '/p', private: '/x',
};
```

Nothing so special.

## The problem

I open the page `localhost:8080/` which redirects `/` to `/p/login` as expected. After a successful login, I perform a `Router.push('/')` with the intention to further re-route the user once again.

The idea is that `/` should get redirect to `/p/login` again, where the navigation guard kicks in and redirects it to `/x/`... But it doesn't. It stays on `/`.

Isn't it supposed to redirect it away from the main page? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do `Router.push('/')` after a login instead of directly to `/x`?

Comment: @btl mainly because the authentication module does not know about the routes, and this is a good solution I figured since it does not need any extra code

Comment: Seeing that you're registering a global guard, all that would be needed to check is adding `if (Store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']) { next() } ...` before the `if (...) {...} if else () {} else {}`.

Comment: If I route to `/` then the `else` case will be fired in the navigation guard, which is a `next() ` call. Why would your solution work any differently?

Comment: I'm not sure if the `Router.push(..)` overrides the redirects specified. Couldn't find anything in the documentation

Comment: Don't all these redirects get confusing? Anyway, guards are not applied to redirects only their targets, which I guess is what is going wrong here. You should really just push to the route you want to go to directly and apply the guard to that route, these type of global guard solutions rarely work well.

Comment: @craig_h thanks for your input, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to this problem. I've reached my goal by pushing to the desired destination directly instead of letting the rerouting do its magic. This works.